# How to say: "this number has not been rounded"?

Tags: numbers, technical

Let's say I count some items and the result is exactly 1000. How do I convey the fact that the actual count was 1000, and that I didn't round the number? It should fit into a sentence like "Overall, we found 1000 items that are related to X."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of *exactly* is fine.  You also could say *[precisely](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/precisely)*

> exactly [Example: *precisely two o'clock*]

Comment: Either word is fine, but using both is pleonastically redundant.

Comment: @TimLymington  Never even heard pleonastic before.  Nice word.  But wouldn't you say "Either word is fine, but using both is pleonastic."  It is already an adjective. "Pleonastically redundant" sounds (this is so much fun) *pleonastic* to my newly informed ear.  LOL.

Comment: @mikeY I'm pretty sure Tim is repeating the repetition for effect.

Comment: @TimLymington. the definition in M-W is **exactly**. What follows in italics is an example. My layout of this was less than clear. I will edit.

Comment: @choster  Yep.  I realized it later.  I did a face palm.

Answer (score 1):

In contexts where a system of modifications is expected, you could say

> **Unadjusted**

Likewise, if rounding is a detrimental by-product of a process, you could also say

> **Unadulterated**

As you said, "exactly" is a fine word:

> Around 3 million dollars were spent,
> but the *exact* number is $2,784,241.00, representing
>
> - trade
> - infrastructure
> - border control
> - unicorn trafficking